# MySQL select and count 2 colums with different where clauses

Tags: mysql, subquery

I think it should be very easy, but it didn't work at all. I have one table and I'd like to generate a chart which are displaying grouped items and with one where clause (column1) it should display the entries with status 0, and with the other where clause (column2) it should display the entries with status 1.

If I do the just one query it works fine, but I'd like to have both (status 0 and status 1) in one combined query.

Status 0 query:

```
SELECT item,quantity, COUNT(status) FROM `table` 
WHERE `retry` = 1
AND `status` = 0
GROUP BY item,quantity
ORDER BY COUNT(status) DESC
```

Status 1 query:

```
SELECT item,quantity, COUNT(status) FROM `table` 
WHERE `retry` = 1
AND `status` = 1
GROUP BY item,quantity
ORDER BY COUNT(status) DESC
```

My try to combine both (didn't work)

```
SELECT t1.item,t1.quantity, COUNT(t2.status), COUNT(t3.status) FROM `table` AS t1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT item,status FROM `table` WHERE `status` = '0' AND `retry` = 1 GROUP BY item,quantity) AS t2
ON t1.ndc = t2.ndc
LEFT JOIN (SELECT item,status FROM `table` WHERE `status` = '1' AND `retry` = 1 GROUP BY item,quantity) AS t3
ON t1.ndc = t3.ndc
WHERE 1
GROUP BY t1.item,t1.quantity
ORDER BY COUNT(t2.status) DESC
```

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Ill use case condition ill write it for you

Comment: How can I provide SQL Fiddle Data in the best way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this please , would it work for you?

please try this

```
 SELECT
    item,quantity,
    COUNT(case when status =1 then 1 end) AS status1,
    COUNT(case when status =0 then 1 end) AS status0
  FROM table
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, but it didn't work as expected, I changed your statement in your where clause also to "AND `status` in( 0,1)" but it will just display NULL depending on which case.

Comment: I just see, that the statement "AND `status` in( 0,1)" count both instead of display it seperate. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @GoldgrubeVerlag it will display both null ? remove group by and order by and retry if it didnt work tell me what kind of result if gives you

Comment: @GoldgrubeVerlag I edit this question I made it simpler

Comment: It just display in one or the other NULL, but also after I removed the group by and order by, it just counts all in status1, and say NULL in status0...

Answer (score 0):

SQL Fiddle Testdata:

```
CREATE TABLE testtable
    (`id` int, `item` bigint(15), `quantity` double,`status` int(2),`retry` int(2))
;

INSERT INTO testtable
    (`id`, `item`, `quantity`, `status`, `retry`)
VALUES
    (1, '452457824', '1.0', '1', '1'),
    (2, '452457824', '1.0', '1', '1'),
    (3, '452457824', '0.5', '1', '1'),
    (4, '452457824', '0.5', '0', '1'),
    (5, '452457824', '0.5', '0', '1'),
    (6, '452457824', '0.5', '0', '1'),
    (7, '21432423', '1.0', '1', '1'),
    (8, '21432423', '1.0', '1', '1'),
    (9, '21432423', '1.0', '0', '1'),
    (10, '21432423', '1.0', '0', '1'),
    (11, '3455467567', '2.0', '1', '1'),
    (12, '3455467567', '2.0', '1', '1'),
    (13, '3455467567', '2.0', '0', '1'),
    (14, '3455467567', '2.0', '0', '1'),
    (15, '3455467567', '2.0', '0', '1'),
    (16, '3455467567', '1.0', '1', '1'),
    (17, '3455467567', '1.0', '1', '1'),
    (18, '3455467567', '1.0', '1', '1')
;
```